# Lodash OrderBy with child attributes

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a requirement where i should sort by object attributes and child attributes , is there a better way to handle this .

```
const testData=[{id:1,name:"test",notes:"test notes",child:[{name:"weight",value:3},{name:"category",value:"testCategory"},{name:"amount",value:2}]},{id:2,name:"test2",notes:"test notes2",child:[{name:"weight",value:4},{name:"category",value:"testCategory"},{name:"amount",value:3}]}]
```

I need to sort by name(asc) and category (desc)

I know it individually like below

```
_.orderBy(testData,['notes'],[asc])
_.orderBy(testData,(t)=>{
              return  _.filter(t.child, (c)=> {
                             return c.name == "category"
                         })[0]['value']

          }
```

How to combine both of them in single orderBY

Comment: See lodash's example for "`user` in ascending order and by `age` in descending order" https://lodash.com/docs/#orderBy

Comment: Yes , the difference is the level of the attribute one is parent level other is at child level how to combine in a single array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use several identity iterators

```
_.orderBy(
    testData, 
    [
        'notes',
         function(item) {
             return _.chain(item).get('child').find({name: 'category'}).get('value').value();
         }
    ], 
    ['asc', 'desc']
);
```

Comment: Same issue , it doesnt sort by the second attribute ,

Comment: fiddle to show its not working https://jsfiddle.net/Kamaraju333/359dysrg/

Comment: @Kamaraju in your data in fiddle there is no `child` key, but you try manipulate it

Comment: @Kamaraju and how you check if you do nothing?

Comment: @Kamaraju this code based on your example data in question, in fiddle another data and code should be changed

Comment: instead of child i have used age field .. its same data for ease of understand i gave that data ,i can update the fiddle show you that its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130306/discussion-between-kamaraju-and-stasovlas).

Comment: Please find the updated fiddle , it still doesnot work.https://jsfiddle.net/Kamaraju333/359dysrg/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use an *iteratee function* to create an *Array* with the data you want to order by.

For example, if we can assume there will be a `.child` called *category* then

```
_.orderBy(testData, data => {
    return [
        data.notes,
        data.child.find(child => child.name === 'category').value
    ];
}, ['asc', 'desc']);
```